# Check if two radio buttons checked, then write. [HTML/JS]

Tags: javascript, html

I can't get my JS/HTML to write if x & y radio buttons is selected...

my code:

http://dumptext.com/6rR25ynt

Comment: Please update your question with more details and post specific code here as well.

Comment: You never declare or assign x or y, nor do you try to print them? You do check they are false for some reason then do nothing. Also there is no element with Id "S4A"  so the condition before that won't do anything either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with your code:
you define the function Pris(), but you miss the closing bracket, so the function is not available. Also the if that is testing whether the radio buttons are checked is not correct. 
Test this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Pris() {

        var S4A = document.getElementById("S4A");
        var S5A = document.getElementById("S5A");

        var Skade1 = document.getElementById("Skade1");
        var Skade2 = document.getElementById("Skade2");
        var Skade3 = document.getElementById("Skade3");
        var Skade4 = document.getElementById("Skade4");

        if (S4A.checked && Skade1.checked){
            document.write("2412kr")
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things going on here. First, in your comparison, I think you're trying to see if both are checked:

```
if (S4A && Skade1 == checked){
```

But to do that would look like this:

```
if (S4A.checked && Skadel1.checked){
```

Second, you have an if block at the bottom which refers to variables which have not been defined:

```
if((x == false) && (y == false)){
}
```

Also as a general note, you want to use `===` instead of `==` as much as possible, because `==` does automatic type coercion.

Finally, and this is actually the first error I found, you have no closing brace for your Pris function. It looks like the `if((x...etc` block wasn't given a closing `}` of its own. Mismatched braces will keep your code from executing.

Hope this helps.

Edited to add: [working jsbin](https://jsbin.com/yaxufev/edit?html,output)

Comment: Even if I got the answer in the first comment, I appriciate you comment too, because you explain why and how the code should work, not just give me the answer, thanks!